# How to lock tabs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Is there a way to lock a desired tab in Firefox to prevent it from being accidentally closed? I know that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> brings back the latest closed tab, but instead I need lock function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The addon [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122) has this function.

[image]

[image]

And a whole heap of other great tab enhancements: Mouse gestures, cycling tabs in used order, change tab sizes... Couldn't live without it.

Comment: Regardless if the basic GUI of Firefox supports locking, you should not go without Tab Mix Plus +1 ;-)

Comment: Just to place a different opinion. I've tried Tab Mix Plus, and found it's mostly about having lots of options you might never use. I, personaly, would go with Permatab or Apptab. They both provide this funcionality without all the extra stuff.

Comment: @Bruce Connor: Would you write your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Mehper: Feel free to write it and get credit for it ;-). This comment is old enough that I won't mind. Most browsers already have a pin function nowadays anyway.

Comment: @Bruce Connor: It's old but good. I'm still using FF 3.6.21 (I have some solid reasons for that) and it does not provide this functionality. So there are still some people who will find your comment useful.

Comment: Note: Shift+click on the tab will protect it (with TabMix Plus), if you don't like menus

Answer (score 2):

[How To Geek has the solution](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/when-to-use-protect-tab-vs-lock-tab-in-firefox/)

> When to Use Protect Tab vs Lock Tab in
>   Firefox One of the best extensions for
>   Firefox is Tab Mix Plus because of the
>   enhancements to the tab browsing that
>   can’t be found elsewhere. There is
>   also another extension called tab
>   browser extensions that provides
>   similar functionality.
>
> There are two options that provide
>   similar but possibly confusing
>   functionality. You can see in the
>   screenshot below the Protect Tab and
>   Lock Tab on the menu.
>
> [image]
>
> Here’s when you should use each
>   feature:
>
> **Protect Tab**
>
> If you want to make sure that a tab
>   cannot be closed. This is useful to
>   make certain you don’t accidentally
>   close a tab.
>
> **Lock Tab**
>
> A lock tab cannot navigate to a new
>   URL. This means that it is “locked” on
>   the current URL. If you have this tab
>   selected and you click a bookmark
>   link, history, or a link on the page,
>   the link will open in a new tab.
>
> You can also combine the two on a
>   single tab. For instance, I both lock
>   and protect my Google Reader tab,
>   which I always keep as the first tab
>   so I can quickly switch back to it

Answer (score 2):

[AppTabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/47734) Pin favicon-sized app tabs to the left side of the tab bar! Inspired by a feature by the same name planned for Firefox 4.0!

[image]

Comment: +1 Pin as app tab is the easiest solution. But you don't need an addon just to pin a tab, just right click and pin, that's all